# UITableView peculiar two-stage updates

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview, restkit

I have a UITableView driven by a NSFetchedResultsController.  The tableview has a custom footer view, and I'm using RestKit to fetch data from an api and map the response into Core Data.

After a RestKit request returns, I'm experiencing a very odd behavior where the response is mapped into core data, my FetchedResultsController sends its delegate (my tableview controller) updates, and the tableview is partially updated, all in less than 1 second.  Then, several seconds later, the tableview finishes updating.  I say the tableview is partially updated because at first, the tablefooterview is not redrawn, and cells are added below it.  It's not until after the delay that the footer moves into place.

I've tried profiling the app with instruments, and this doesn't seem to be a CPU based delay in drawing/loading cells. I've also tried simply setting the title label of the cell only when configuring cells to minimize complexity.  I also see the same behavior both on the device and the simulator.

I'd really like to track down and eliminate this delay, as it really causes a bad user experience.

An except from the logs:

```
2012-09-18 10:39:43.695 MyApp[28881:470f] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController controllerWillChangeContent:] [Line 236] controller => <NSFetchedResultsController: 0xe657570>
2012-09-18 10:39:43.695 MyApp[28881:470f] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:] [Line 267] controller => <NSFetchedResultsController: 0xe657570>
(...19 similiar lines...)
2012-09-18 10:39:43.703 MyApp[28881:470f] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController controllerDidChangeContent:] [Line 301] controller => <NSFetchedResultsController: 0xe657570>
2012-09-18 10:39:43.705 MyApp[28881:470f] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0xed5f890; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xed5f9b0>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0xed5eab0> 2 indexes [0, 0]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.706 MyApp[28881:470f] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0xe659e50; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xe659f70>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0xe657b50> 2 indexes [0, 1]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.708 MyApp[28881:470f] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0xe65aca0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xe65adc0>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0xe65a6f0> 2 indexes [0, 2]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.709 MyApp[28881:470f] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0xe9e1890; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xe9b1e10>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0xe9c59d0> 2 indexes [0, 3]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.711 MyApp[28881:470f] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0x13c6f230; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x13c6ed80>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0xe9e0fb0> 2 indexes [0, 4]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.712 MyApp[28881:470f] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0xe9e2230; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xe9b1a60>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0xe9e0ea0> 2 indexes [0, 5]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.713 MyApp[28881:470f] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0x13c6fef0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x13c70010>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0xe95dca0> 2 indexes [0, 6]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.714 MyApp[28881:470f] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0xeb599f0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xeb59b10>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0xe9e2a10> 2 indexes [0, 7]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.715 MyApp[28881:470f] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0x13c70d10; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x13c6fea0>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0xe9e1790> 2 indexes [0, 8]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.717 MyApp[28881:470f] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0xed616c0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xed5ee80>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0xe9e1d50> 2 indexes [0, 9]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.718 MyApp[28881:470f] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0xe65bb00; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xe65b680>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0xe65b1c0> 2 indexes [0, 11]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.720 MyApp[28881:470f] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0x13c71c00; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x13c71770>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0x13c6f1d0> 2 indexes [0, 13]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.721 MyApp[28881:470f] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0xe65c900; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xe65c4a0>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0xe659ce0> 2 indexes [0, 14]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.722 MyApp[28881:470f] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0xe65d720; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xe65d2c0>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0xe659de0> 2 indexes [0, 15]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.723 MyApp[28881:470f] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0xe65e5a0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xe65e110>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0xe65d2a0> 2 indexes [0, 16]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.739 MyApp[28881:470f] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0x91bf9e0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x9197560>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0x91c9960> 2 indexes [0, 17]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.740 MyApp[28881:470f] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0x93e8d50; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x93dd090>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0x93cb8b0> 2 indexes [0, 18]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.741 MyApp[28881:470f] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0x13c727b0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x13c728d0>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0x13c72420> 2 indexes [0, 19]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.742 MyApp[28881:470f] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0x93e6ff0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x93da000>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0x93d4d10> 2 indexes [0, 21]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.744 MyApp[28881:470f] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0xed62510; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xed620a0>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0xed5ed80> 2 indexes [0, 22]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.772 MyApp[28881:c07] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController controllerWillChangeContent:] [Line 236] controller => <NSFetchedResultsController: 0xe657570>
2012-09-18 10:39:43.777 MyApp[28881:c07] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:] [Line 267] controller => <NSFetchedResultsController: 0xe657570>
(...19 similiar lines...)
2012-09-18 10:39:43.788 MyApp[28881:c07] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController controllerDidChangeContent:] [Line 301] controller => <NSFetchedResultsController: 0xe657570>
2012-09-18 10:39:43.790 MyApp[28881:c07] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0x13c7be10; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x13c7bf30>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0x13c7b080> 2 indexes [0, 0]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.791 MyApp[28881:c07] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0xe9e2be0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xe9e1b10>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0xe977940> 2 indexes [0, 1]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.792 MyApp[28881:c07] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0xe9e38b0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xe9e2190>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0xe9c0bc0> 2 indexes [0, 2]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.793 MyApp[28881:c07] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0xe9e4680; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0xe9e41f0>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0xe9e3d60> 2 indexes [0, 3]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.794 MyApp[28881:c07] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:] [Line 34] cell => <RDRMarketBooksCell: 0x13c7ccc0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 79); autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x13c7cde0>>, indexPath => <NSIndexPath 0x13c7b270> 2 indexes [0, 4]
2012-09-18 10:39:43.802 MyApp[28881:c07] -[RDRMarketBooksViewController productsDidLoad:forCategory:error:] [Line 319] resource => <RDRRangedResource: 0x9533390> => {
```

And the relevant methods from my UITableViewController subclass:

```
- (void)configureCell:(RDRMarketBooksCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSParameterAssert(cell);
    NSParameterAssert(indexPath);

    Trace(@"cell => %@, indexPath => %@", cell, indexPath);

    NSAssert([cell isKindOfClass:[RDRMarketBooksCell class]], @"should be a market books cell");
    id<RDRAPIProduct> product = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.titleLabel.text = product.name;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableViewDelegate

// Configuring Rows for the Table View

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 79.0;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (!tableViewIsUpdating) {
        [(RDRMarketBooksCell *)cell refreshSecondaryValues];
    }
}

// Managing Selections

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id<RDRAPIProduct> product = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    BOOL shouldSelect = YES;
    if (product) {
        shouldSelect = (product.slug != nil);
    }
    return (shouldSelect ? indexPath : nil);
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    id<RDRAPIProduct> product = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (RDRIsiPad()) {
        [[RDRApplicationDelegate sharedDelegate] presentDetailsWithProduct:product];
    }

    [self.delegate viewController:self didPickProduct:product];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UITableViewDataSource

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RDRMarketBooksCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kRDRMarketBooksCellIdentifier];
    NSAssert(cell, @"cell should not be nil");

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [[fetchedResultsController sections] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

/*
 Assume self has a property 'tableView' -- as is the case for an instance of a UITableViewController
 subclass -- and a method configureCell:atIndexPath: which updates the contents of a given cell
 with information from a managed object at the given index path in the fetched results controller.
 */

- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    Trace(@"controller => %@", controller);
    if (controller == fetchedResultsController) {
        tableViewIsUpdating = YES;
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo
           atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {
    Trace(@"controller => %@", controller);

    if (controller == fetchedResultsController) {
        switch(type) {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;
        }
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {
    Trace(@"controller => %@", controller);

    if (controller == fetchedResultsController) {
        UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

        switch(type) {

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath]
                                 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;
        }
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    Trace(@"controller => %@", controller);
    if (controller == fetchedResultsController) {
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
        tableViewIsUpdating = NO;

//        double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
//        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
//        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
//            [self fetchSecondaryValues];
//        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved.  The NSFetchedResultsController was using the primaryManagedObjectContext of the RKManagedObjectStore.  I switched it over to the mainQueueManagedObjectContext and the issue was solved.

I looked more closely at RestKit and the mainQueueManagedObjectContext is a child of the primaryManagedObjectContext (and then discovered that this fact is mentioned in the docs).  I had originally thought that RestKit mappings occur on the primaryManagedObjectContext, but now my guess is that they occur on the mainQueueManagedObjectContext, and are saved on a low priority thread to the primaryManagedObjectContext, and then to the persistent store.  With my NSFetchedResultsController previously attached to the primaryManagedObjectContext, this would explain the long delay before results fully appeared.  The need to use the mainQueueManagedObjectContext in this case was not however, apparent in the docs.  In retrospect, however, the docs do mention that the purpose of the mainQueueManagedObjectContext is so that data can be written to the persistent store through the primaryManagedObjectContext without causing the UI to stutter.

My code to create the NSFetchedResultsController now looks like:

```
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore] mainQueueManagedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fr = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"RDRProduct"];
    fr.fetchBatchSize = 20;
    fr.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY categories.slug == %@", category.slug];
    fr.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sortingTitle" ascending:YES]];
    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:category.slug];
    NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fr
                                                                                               managedObjectContext:context
                                                                                                 sectionNameKeyPath:@"sortingSection"
                                                                                                          cacheName:category.slug];
```

and my tableview now works properly.